# Is there a code editor plugin for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, editor, code-editor

Is there a Code Editor plugin for chrome? like maybe gedit for chrome or vim for chrome. It is really tiring moving between windows a lot so I would like to have a code editor in my browser.

Just open a new tab, open a file and start editing or writing you code. Is there such a thing?

Edit 1: they should be able to support HDL languages (VHDL or Verilog).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.edaplayground.com/

Is on online editor and simulation environment for HDL code samples and includes UVM. It allows running code snippets to linked to stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of cloud IDEs that you can use on a browser. Here are some samples.

[Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io)
or 
[CodeEnvy](https://codenvy.com)

Comment: They do not support all useful programming languages, I'm specifically looking for HDL languages support.

Comment: @ProWi, Well, they do support a wide range of programming languages. HDL code is what is not commonly edited on a browser. I have never seen VHDL simulation or synthesis on a browser.

Comment: that's why I don't want a complete IDE, just a text editor that can be merged into chrome. with syntax highlighting for HDL languages of course.

Comment: @ProWi I don't if your requirement has to be specifically a browser. But i can recommend you the text editor Sublime Text 2 or 3. It is very fast because is not made on java and it is very extensible and fast. Don't use a lot of resources and there is an extension that add VHDL highlighting to it.

Answer (score 0):

cloud9 is better IDE for me. It works exactly what i need .